# Large messages with ReplayingDecoder

Tags: netty

I have a connection between two Java processes, both sides using Netty.  The decoding side uses a ReplayingDecoder and uses it to deserialise a more complex message type.

Most of the messages are quite small.  However I have discovered today a performance issue with larger messages (~4MB) which occur very infrequently.

I have already surmised the following

- The messages don't need to be 4MB, I can make them smaller
- ReplayingDecoder is probably not the best choice for handling large messages like this, without some sort of length header to saving parsing over and over

That aside I was unsure of why it was so slow.  I was taking a good few minutes for the message to transmit from one side to another.

The write does the following

- Create dynamic buffer
- Write entire message to buffer
- Call channel.write() once with buffer

Which appears to be reasonably fast (observing when the future completes).  The message is about 4MB in size.

Looking on the decode side I can see it hits my handler every few seconds where it tries to parse something, throws, replays, waits for more data etc.

However I was only seeing the buffer size indicating the available data increasing by 50k or so every time the handler was being called (every second or so).  I would've expected the buffer to fill much faster than this.

I am on a local network, in fact two processes on the same machine using the loopback address to connect to network speed should not be a major factor.

Is this expected behaviour?  Is my repeated parsing process, which will be blocking the handler and anything serialised with it from running and perhaps filling the buffer as fast as I would've expected?

I am using Netty 3.1.1.GA (quite old, can upgrade to test if something may have improved this)

Any more info I can provide or places to debug further please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

According to ReplayingDecoder Java doc

"Performance can be worse if the network is slow and the message format is complicated. your decoder might have to decode the same part of the message over and over again."

To avoid this, you have to maintain the state of decoding using checkpoints.

you can get more information form [ReplayingDecoder](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3.2/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/replay/ReplayingDecoder.java) Java doc comments.

Comment: Yeah I understand that but this is two processes on the same machine (added more detail above) so the network should not be the slowness that I am seeing.

Comment: @MikeQ you have said that, you are decoding "more complex message type", So have you tried checkpoints which mentioned in the ReplayingDecoder Java Doc?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into `HttpMessageDecoder` source code in Netty.  You will find how you can deal with a large content.  Basically, you call `checkpoint()` frequently as Jestan suggested, and generate smaller message chunks.